# Why Azure treating 400 (Bad request) response as SCIM implementation error in provider?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, scim2

**Audit Log:**

[image]

I have chose to not to DELETE group according to scim specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.6

> Clients request resource removal via DELETE.  Service providers MAY
> choose not to permanently delete the resource

But then Azure treats it as error, Below is what I see in Audit Log, Did I understood the specification correctly or am I missing something?

> Failed to delete Group '' in customappsso; Error: The SCIM
> endpoint is not fully compatible with the Azure Active Directory SCIM
> client. Please refer to the Azure Active Directory SCIM provisioning
> documentation and adapt the SCIM endpoint to be able to process
> provisioning requests from Azure Active Directory. StatusCode:
> BadRequest Message: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an
> exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response'
> property of this exception for details. Web Response:
> {"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"detail":"DELETE
> group not supported","status":null,"scimType":"mutability"}. This
> operation was retried 0 times. It will be retried again after this
> date: 2020-03-16T17:42:08.0940986Z UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shouldn't come up if you uncheck delete in the attribute mappings. You're right that the delete endpoint does not need to be implemented.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes#editing-user-attribute-mappings